# Difficulty accessing entire hash in ruby with data pulled from api

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm currently trying to pull data via the Yelp API, and can only seem to access half of the hash.

This code:

> client = Yelp::Client.new
>
> include Yelp::V2::Search::Request
>
> request = Location.new(
>                :city => 'Melbourne',
>                :limit => 1)  response = client.search(request)
>
> puts response

Will output the full hash of

> {"region"=>{"span"=>{"latitude_delta"=>0.0, "longitude_delta"=>0.0},
>   "center"=>{"latitude"=>28.0772451, "longitude"=>-80.6045478}},
>   "total"=>2324, "businesses"=>[{"is_claimed"=>false, "rating"=>4.5,
>   "mobile_url"=>"http://m.yelp.com/biz/el-ambia-cubano-melbourne",
>   "rating_img_url"=>"http://s3-media2.fl.yelpassets.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png",
>   "review_count"=>168, "name"=>"El Ambia Cubano",
>   "snippet_image_url"=>"http://s3-media1.fl.yelpassets.com/photo/NgfGcZGdYlhTO18p8Shqrw/ms.jpg",
>   "rating_img_url_small"=>"http://s3-media2.fl.yelpassets.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png",
>   "url"=>"http://www.yelp.com/biz/el-ambia-cubano-melbourne",
>   "phone"=>"3213278389", "snippet_text"=>"4.5 stars to me - rounded up
>   because the kids liked it too.\n\nWent here for lunch based mostly on
>   yelp reviews. Rest of my crew voted against Indian or Thai....",
>   "image_url"=>"http://s3-media3.fl.yelpassets.com/bphoto/pnZSlPiBDl1bS9w7saOAZA/ms.jpg",
>   "categories"=>[["Cuban", "cuban"]],
>   "display_phone"=>"+1-321-327-8389",
>   "rating_img_url_large"=>"http://s3-media4.fl.yelpassets.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png",
>   "id"=>"el-ambia-cubano-melbourne", "is_closed"=>false,
>   "location"=>{"city"=>"Melbourne", "display_address"=>["950 E Melbourne
>   Ave", "Melbourne, FL 32901"], "geo_accuracy"=>8.0,
>   "postal_code"=>"32901", "country_code"=>"US", "address"=>["950 E
>   Melbourne Ave"], "coordinate"=>{"latitude"=>28.0771809,
>   "longitude"=>-80.6044922}, "state_code"=>"FL"}}]}

I can access the region info by using

> puts response["region"]

But I can't seem to access the rest of the hash? I'm specifically trying to extract the business name. What am I missing and need to do to access the entire hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`businesses` seems to be an array. Something like

```
response["businesses"][0]["name"]
```

Will retrive the name of the first business

Comment: `response["businesses"][0]["name"]  => "El Ambia Cubano" `

Comment: Is retrieving the first element in the `businesses` array. But in this case the array has only has one business. If eventually the API returns 2 or more business (assuming that's possible, I dont have knowledge about the API you are using), you could retrieve the others by doing `["businesses"][0]`,  `["businesses"][1]`,  `["businesses"][2]`, etc

Comment: `response["businesses"].size` gives you the number of businesses